# python2.7.5 encodings.idna not present

Tags: python, encoding, dns

caveat: I have to use python 2.7.5 for this project.

my problem is the following:
I'm trying to convert a umlaut-domain represented in IDN-Form(e.g. müller.de) to an ACE-String(e.g. xn--mller-kva.de).
Reading the official python documentation I found `encodings.idna` which should be introduced in python 2.3.
Howsoever I don't seem to find `encodings.idna` by doing `dir(encodings)` all I get is:

```
['CodecRegistryError',
 '__builtin__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '_aliases',
 '_cache',
 '_import_tail',
 '_norm_encoding_map',
 '_unknown',
 'aliases',
 'ascii',
 'codecs',
 'hex_codec',
 'normalize_encoding',
 'search_function',
 'utf_8']
```

What am I holding wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `unicode_object.encode('idna')`:

```
>>> import encodings
>>> encodings.idna
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'idna'
>>> u'müller.de'.encode('idna')
'xn--mller-kva.de'
>>> encodings.idna
<module 'encodings.idna' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/idna.pyc'>
```

It seems it is not imported until it is used or it is explicitly imported.

```
>>> import encodings
>>> encodings.idna
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'idna'
>>> import encodings.idna
>>> encodings.idna
<module 'encodings.idna' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/idna.pyc'>
```